# Ubuntu 16.10 freezes randomly on MSI board with AMD cpu

Tags: 16.10, freeze

My computer just freezes randomly when I am using Ubuntu 16.10. I had this issue with another computer (laptop with Intel CPU) and was never able to resolve the issue.

When I was using 4.8 generic Ubuntu kernel, the freeze happened more often. Now I upgraded the kernel to 4.10. I am still having issues with this kernel. The freeze happens less often, but it still freezes ramdomly.

When the computer freezes, I can't do anything. I can't switch it to console (Ctrl + F1); I can't force quit it using Print Screen key; I can't do anything except hitting reset button on my computer.

Freeze happened when I was listening to an audio one time. When that happened, the audio stuck for 1 second, then it went silent.

I'm using GeForce GTX 750Ti and AMD FX.

I overclocked my CPU; however, this happened without overclocking, and the temperature of CPU never went above 40C; the temperature usually stays at 15C.

== EDIT ==

I have no swap.

I have 16GB ram which never have gotten full. (Usually 80% was free).

It does not really matter what I do to cause freezes. My computer froze when I moved a cursor.

I am using NVidia's proprietary driver.

I can't type any commands after freeze. It completely freezes; I have mentioned that Ctrl + F1 does not work after the freeze. This part really bugged me because I couldn't read the logs.

16.04 LTS was worse on previous computer, but I have not tested 16.04 LTS on this computer, so I can't make any conjecture on 16.04 LTS.

Overclocking might not be the problem since this happened without overclocking.

Comment: Have you installed the Nvidia proprietary drivers?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `cat /var/log/syslog` right after a freeze? Please post it at: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: How much RAM? How much swap? Very possible that it's a hard drive problem. Do you know how to fsck the drive? Do you know how to review the SMART data and run the SMART tests? Do you know how to bad block a hard drive?

Comment: The current kernel for 16.04 LTS is Linux Ubuntu 4.4.0-xx-generic.  The whole idea behind the LTS is to offer a stable platform and not to update anything until it is proven stable.  You seem to prefer to push the technology which is perfectly fine.  But by upgrading to unstable and/or development releases you have to expect problems such as freezes.  If stability is important to you I'd recommend going back to a clean 16.04 LTS release, without any hardware overclocking.

Comment: I have replied the comments by editing the post.